# How to realize looping mechanism, where function calls self until some condition is not met, or queueing function calls

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to translate an application from python (with TKinter) to Java. 
Tkinter has a looping mechanism such as:

```
<!-- language: python -->

def checkState():
    if checkCond1():
        root.after_idle(cond1Loop)
    elif checkCond2():
        root.after_idle(cond2Loop)
    elif checkCond3():
        root.after_idle(cond3Loop)
    else:
        print('not found known state...')
        root.update_idletasks() # waits for idle Tk tasks
        root.after_idle(checkState)

def cond1Loop():
    # some checks here, may be looping deeper
    root.after_idle(cond1Loop)


def cond2Loop():
    # some checks here, may be looping deeper
    root.after_idle(cond2Loop)


def cond3Loop():
    # some checks here, may be looping deeper
    root.after_idle(cond3Loop)

root = Tk()
mainWindow = Frame(root)
# some win init here
root.after_idle(checkState)# calls function when no idle tasks
root.mainloop()
```

My first try was to realize it using timers, but can not stop the timer from within its own function:

```
<!-- language: java-->
private void mainLogicLoop(){
    javax.swing.Timer localtimer = new javax.swing.Timer(100, e -> {
        //finding state
        if(checkCond1()){
            System.out.println("I am at cond 1.");
            cond1Loop();
            //here i need to stop this timer,
            //but localtimer is invisible from here.
            //cond1Loop() will run its own timer...
        }else
        if(checkCond2()){
            System.out.println("I am at cond 2.");
            cond2Loop();
            //here i need to stop this timer,
            //but localtimer is invisible from here.
            //cond2Loop() will run its own timer...
        }else
        if(checkCond3()){
            System.out.println("I am at cond 3.");
            cond3Loop();
            //here i need to stop this timer,
            //but localtimer is invisible from here.
            //cond3Loop() will run its own timer...
        }else{
            System.out.println("No known conditions found.");
        }
    localtimer.start();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    mainLogicLoop();
}
```

Please, do not suggest outer scripts, such as Sikuli and platform-depending features. I need as "pure-and-native" Java, as it can be.

--update--

Using JDK 1.8 because running on WinXP

Comment: Any reason why you are using javax.swing.Timer instead of java.util.Timer?

Comment: There is no reason - googling have returned an example using  javax.swing.Timer

Comment: Why are you using the Timer in the first place? Can you describe the core algorithm which requires you to use a timer? Sounds like an over-complication......

Comment: Its just a try to realize looping mechanism, a point to start the exploration.

Comment: I understand, that Timer is not a good thing but it does what i need... I would be glad to know more efficient way to do such things

Comment: I would suggest using ScheduledExecutorService instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @cricket_007, this looping mechanizm was easily realized using ExecutorService. Working code example: 
in constructor i create service `ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();`
 and at every loop's end i call 
`service.submit(() -> loopname());`